# Microsoft Portable Client Library - MessageContractAttribute isWrapped not defined

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, portable-class-library

I am attempting to use Microsoft's Portable Library Tools, to create a common "Portable" project that can be used by both a Silverlight and a WPF application.

I've run into trouble with adding a Service Reference to a 3rd party WebService to the portable project. It seems that the Portable Class Library does not support the *isWrapped* attribute of the MessageContractAttribute class, e.g. if I create the client Stubs directly in a Silverlight application, the stub looks like this:

```
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(IsWrapped=false)]
public partial class ServiceRequest1 {
```

But in my Portable project, it looks like this, missing the *IsWrapped* property setting:

```
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute()]
public partial class ServiceRequest1 {
```

It seems it can't be set manually either, it just isn't available / undefined. The result is, my Web Service SOAP request has an unwanted wrapper tags around it, causing the server to respond with a malformed request error message.

I'm wondering are there any known workarounds for this? Is there any other way to switch the wrapper off, or does anyone know why the IsWrapped property is not available?

It would be great if I could get this to work, thereby my WPF and Silverlight solutions could share it.